# How to find the error?

Tags: errors

I was typing easily when I got the message:

```
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Gr\'afico de uma Fun\c 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.102 \begin{document}
```

I undone everything I have done this afternoon, but it don't compile anymore.

Is there a way to find where is the error?

Comment: first quick thing to try is delete all your auxiliary files (.aux, .toc, etc.) and try recompiling

Comment: you should delete your aux file and toc file, but the actual error is probably a fragile command in the section heading that starts  `Gr\'afico de uma Fun`   the command may need to be prefixed with `\protect` but as you have not shown a test file it is hard to say exactly.

Comment: @David Carlisle \colorbox{pink}{
\begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
\section{Gráfico de uma Função\label{gráfico}}
\end{minipage}
}

Comment: don't use accented letters in `\label`

Comment: I removed the accent, but the problem remains.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I should add \addcontentsline somewhere?

Comment: @spohreis: No. I did not see the `\label` in your comment. David is right. Just say `\label{grafico}`, without the accent

Comment: You should always post a complete example, I will add an example as an answer that works without error, please edit to be a similar complete document that shows the error (after deleting any aux and toc files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use ascii characters in `\label`, this runs without error

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{1,.5,.5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\colorbox{pink}{ \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
\section{Gráfico de uma Função\label{grafico}}
\end{minipage} } 
\end{document}
```